# Is *html selector really needed?

Tags: html, css

I just read this code somewhere.

```
*html #menu ul{margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;width:960px;}
```

I know * means the selector means any element in css.
But is this needed here? Since it works totally the same without it.Or is it some kind of CSS hacks in specific browsers ?

Comment: It's a hack to target IE7. There's no space between the asterisk and the rest of the selector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a CSS hack targeted at Internet Explorer 6 and below. More modern browsers should ignore any of the styles applied using `*html`.

**List of browsers which will apply the styles**

- IE4-6/Win
- IE4-5/Mac
- IE7+, when in backwards compatibility mode (aka quirks mode)

**List of browsers which will ignore the styles**

- IE7+, when in Standards Compatibility mode
- Firefox
- NS6.0-7.2
- NS4.x
- Opera 5+ (I don't know about versions 1 through 4.)
- Safari
- Konqueror 3
- iCab 3

Source: [* html ("Star HTML") CSS Hack](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-html/)

So, provided your document is valid then IE7+ should display the page in [standards mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and will ignore the styles. If the page is being displayed in 'quirks mode' then the styles will be applied in IE7+.

Answer (score 0):

The Star Selector Hack

The star selector hack, also known as the star-HTML hack and the Tan hack, because it was first described in detail by Edwardson Tan, is the most widely used filter; it relies on a peculiar behavior in Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6. Even though it’s often labeled a hack, I’ve included it in this section on filters because, despite the fact that it exploits a browser bug, it uses a valid CSS selector. The selector, however, should never match any elements; all browsers, except Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6, understand this fact and ignore the rule.

The technique is simply to apply a descendant selector that makes use of the universal selector. The universal selector is, of course, valid CSS, so don’t be confused and start thinking that using the universal selector is bad news. The most common form of the technique (and the origin of its name) is to compose a rule with the * html selector. This constitutes valid CSS, but it shouldn’t match any elements. The selector should apply the rule to any html element that’s the descendant of any other element and, as html is the root element, it’s never a descendant of any other element.

However, while most other browsers ignore it, Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6 will interpret this selector as if there was no universal selector, like the rule below:

```
html {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Thus, the star selector hack is a safe way of applying CSS rules to Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6 without affecting other browsers.

You’d use it like this:

```
.test {
  position: fixed;
}
* html .test{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Only Internet Explorer 6 and earlier versions will apply the latter rule; other browsers will ignore it.

Source : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/workaroundsfilters#workaroundsfilters__sect_starhtmlselector

Comment: Not in this case it doesn't. It's a hack to get that rule to target IE7 only. There's no space between it and `html`

Comment: Actually and ie6,but who would use such an old browser,Also in the linked provided it mentions "Thus, the star selector hack is a safe way of applying CSS rules to Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6 without affecting other browsers"                           Cant understand why you downvoted.Nevermind,cheers

Comment: So why are you talking about the `*` selector being a "catch all" in the OP's question, when it's actually a workaround for IE6/7?

Comment: Its a catch all for the elements not the browsers,its okay mate you probably misread it.I would love to know what you found wrong so I can correct it.

Comment: **Whitespace is signficiant in CSS selectors**. `*html` is _not_ the same as `* html`. You're answering the OP's question as if they had found the latter

Comment: Ow I see what you mean,Im sorry I will fix this soon.

Comment: Updated my answer with info from the source!this time it correct :D

Comment: thks, Actually I　tried removing the Whitespace it works no differently. So *html and * html works the same as it looks like. Fortunately no one's using ancient browsers.:D